# Antenna and Base Receiver Set Operations

Tags: java, algorithm, set

[Problem Statement](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkgbdn3oypnz4zw/antenna.pdf)

We have a set of antennas and base receiver stations, as given in the problem statement. What I've reasoned so far -:

1. A union of sets of base receiver stations allotted to a number of antennas will give me the number of base stations in range of either or all those antennas.
2. An intersection of sets of base receiver stations of a number of antennas will give me a set of stations common to these antennas.
3. The difference between union and intersection of these sets will give me a set of receivers unique to the antennas, thus removing the problem of interference. I need to obtain a set with maximum such elements.

A powerset approach (selecting the best set from the powerset of such difference sets) would be quite exhaustive if the number of inputs is substantial. How should I be going about this problem? For a Java implementation, I was thinking of either using a set of sets or a list of sets.

Comment: how many antennas and receivers are you expecting to have? this looks like an NP-hard problem (variation to Independent Set problem)...

Comment: ile: is my approach correct though? The 'substantial' statement I made was just an afterthought. I wish to know whether my approach is sound, and if it is, how I'm supposed to generate the difference sets.

Comment: one simple way to iterate over all subsets is to go from i=0 to 2^n (exclusive). For each i, look over its n bits, if a bit is set then include it into a set. If you need more you can search for "generating all subsets"

Comment: So generating all subsets is what I should be looking for? Suppose I have a0, a1 and a2. I need to take a0 and a1 together, find their union and intersection, and then the difference. I do this for all other pairs of sets available. Then I  Move on to triplets. After collecting all difference sets, I find the one with maximum length. Should I be looking for subsets of a set then, or something else?